# How to detect a click as soon as possible in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code on my webpage:

```html
    <span id="my-id">Button</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("my-id").onclick = function(event) { alert("Clicked Button!"); };</script>
```

On my webpage, the actual code is like this:

```
<html>Lot of markup</html>
<button>My button</button>
<script>My one line script shown in the above snippet.</script>
<iframe>Two iframes</iframe>
<html>More HTML</html>
```

Since the `script` tag comes just after the button, it should be detecting the click but it doesn't. The click is detected only after the page has loaded. Why is that?

Is there anything that I can do to detect the click as soon as possible.

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/nek11weu/  What do you mean by "after the page has loaded"?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: it is a good (_rather the best_) practice to execute scripts after the page is loaded completely...

Comment: I edited your question to make your code live. It seems to work fine. You need to supply a real [mcve]

Comment: @David There is a lot of content on the webpage and the click seems to be detected only after the whole page has loaded.

Comment: @gkb — No. That's cargo culting. Waiting for the page to load completely is just a good way of ensuring that the elements you are trying to access really do exist. There's nothing wrong with running the script sooner if you know the element exists (you just have to be aware that the script will block the rest of the page from parsing while it runs and decide if that is worth it).

Comment: it might be that the page hangs up for a second and appears to be not detecting a click while the events are scheduled to arrive after all reflows

Comment: @Quentin - Correct, but that was meant for scripts having to do with the DOM elements....

Comment: @gkb — Which this does, and the element is before the script, so it is fine.

Comment: @WayNo I have edited the question with more details. I don't understand the reflow parts. Does the browser wait before registering the clicks? I thought it will happen as soon as it sees the script.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the browser will have rendered the element before executing the script, even though the script follows the element in DOM order. [Read this from google](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/closure-library-discuss/G-7Ltdavy0E)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the onclick event directly on the `span` tag.  That would make it so that it works as soon as that part of the DOM has loaded, rather than waiting until the whole page has loaded to execute the script.

```
<span onclick="myFunction()">Button</span>
```

**Caution:**

Note that if your `myFunction()` is part of a script that will be loaded at the end, it still won't work.  You could do something simple here, however, including the whole functionality right in the markup.  For example:

```
<span onclick="alert('You clicked me')">Button</span>
```

Or something else simple.

Comment: Advice that that's not good when you want to depend on scopes of other scripts, you'll have to share things through the global object

Comment: I agree that it's not best practice, but it seems that the user wants to know how to run something immediately.

Comment: *it still won't work*: it depends, if the script declares an URL to be loaded (src), if `myFunction` is globally declared it'll work because it'll be on the global object, but that will only happen when that script be executed (its URL basically needs to be loaded).